# visual c# delete control during runtime

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a programatically created ListBoxItem which contains a stack panels containing a checkbox. I have an event handler attached to the checkbox and when the user checks the checkbox I want the ListBoxItem and all its children to be deleted. How should I do this?

Comment: Hmm, it's not a C# question.  Is it a WPF question?

Answer (score 2):

remove the control from the collection it belongs to
[Helpful link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82785s1h%28VS.80%29.aspx)